# getting a time difference in android

Tags: android

First i want to store the current time when the user lunch my app. Then after that when the user launch my app again then i also get the current time and compare the current time with previous stored time and check whether the time difference becomes "one day" or not.Because if the time difference becomes "one day" then i will do something in my app.
But i can understand how to do this.

I know about

```
Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String ts = tsLong.toString();
```

to get the current time. here what actually does "currentTimeMillis"???  But i dont understand how  can i reach my total goal.
Please can anyone suggest me how to solve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to store the last time the user has opened your app you will probably need to use SharedPreferences and store the time the user has opened your app to then compare the stored value with the next time the app is opened, checking if the time difference is greater than 1 day.

First, answering your actual question: System.currentTimeMillis() returns the number of milliseconds ellapsed since the "epoch" (1970 Jan 1 00:00:00). It is on documentation.

Now, for storing the time the user has opened your app you should do something like this on your main activity's onCreate (or maybe your Application's onCreate, depending on your scenario):

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
long openTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
preferences.edit()
        .putLong(OPEN_TIME_KEY, openTime)
        .commit();
```

And finally, for checking the time difference between the last and the current opening of your app (you should do this before the first code snippet, not to override the stored preferences before reading it):

```
long day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Milliseconds in a day. Define this as a constant
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
long openTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long lastTime = preferences.getLong(OPEN_TIME_KEY, 0);
if ((openTime - lastTime) > day) {
    // do your thing here
}
```

You should obviously reuse some variables on both snippets (openTime and preferences), but I did it like this anyway for you to understand the concept and implement it by yourself and not just copy the code. Anyway, I think that does the job, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

you need to use full timestamp to get what you want...
here is an example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58";
    String dateStop = "01/15/2012 10:31:48";

    //HH converts hour in 24 hours format (0-23), day calculation
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;

    try {
        d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
        d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

        //in milliseconds
        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
        System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
        System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
        System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: How can i get the current time from the user in such format "dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58".??